# How to call ancestor constructors sequentially in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, oop, constructor

I am trying to learn OOP in Javascript, and my main inspiration so far has been the following site: http://phrogz.net/js/classes/OOPinJS2.html

The problem that I am facing is that I have a class, which has a parent class, which again has a parent class, and that I am not able to find a clever way to pass arguments through the chain of constructors up to the top-level parent.

I am able to pass it up one level, but then my code runs into an infinite recursive loop.

The following code sketches the problem:

```js
// Define inheritance function:

Function.prototype.inheritsFrom = function( parentClassOrObject ){   
  this.prototype = new parentClassOrObject;
  this.prototype.constructor = this;
  this.prototype.parent = parentClassOrObject.prototype;  
} 

// Define objects (classes) and inheritance structure:

function Human(name){
  this.name         = name;
}

function Criminal(name,crime){
  this.parent.constructor.call(this, name);
  this.crime        = crime;  
}
Criminal.inheritsFrom(Human); 

function Prisoner(name,crime,centence){
  this.parent.constructor.call(this, name, crime);
  this.centence     = centence;
}
Prisoner.inheritsFrom(Criminal); 

// Create instances:

h  = new Human('Anne')               // > Human {name: "Anne"}    
c  = new Criminal('Jack','theft')    // > Criminal {name: "Jack", crime: "theft"}    
p  = new Prisoner('Jon','murder',21) // > Error

// > Error description: Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded(…)
```

Obviously the Prisoner successfully calls the parent constructor, i.e., the Criminal constructor. But then when the Criminal constructor calls the parent constructor then "this" is still referring to the same Prisoner object, so that the parent constructor call again will be to the Criminal constructor (instead of the intended Human constructor), and so an infinite recursive loop if formed.

Is there an easy (and preferably sexy) way to solve the problem? Or maybe a better way to implement the inheritance?

Comment: Your inheritance model is wrong.  Read http://blog.slaks.net/2013-09-03/traditional-inheritance-in-javascript/

Comment: And you can't put `parent` on the prototype, because there is only one prototype for all levels.

Comment: @SLaks When I tried the final `inherits` function from your blog, I got the error _Cannot redefine property: prototype_ - any ideas to why and how to best solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the post from @SLaks and the excellent [plain-English guide to Javascript prototypes](http://sporto.github.io/blog/2013/02/22/a-plain-english-guide-to-javascript-prototypes/) by Sebastian Porto, I set up the solution that is sketched up below.

If there are anything I am missing with this solution, please let me know. :)

Ideally I think it would be nice if the inheritance could be set up from within the constructor, but that does not seem to be feasible... So this solution seems to be as good as it gets. :)

```js
inherits = function(child, parent) {
  child.parent       = parent;
  child.prototype    = Object.create(parent.prototype, {
    constructor: {
      value: child, 
      enumerable: false,
      writable: true,
      configurable: true
    }
  });  
  console.log('Inheritance set: ' + child.name + '.parent = ' + parent.name);  
};

function Human(name){
  this.name         = name;  
}

function Criminal(name,crime){
  Human.call(this, name);
  this.crime        = crime;
}inherits(Criminal,Human);  

function Prisoner(name,crime,centence){  
  Criminal.call(this, name, crime);
  this.centence     = centence;
}inherits(Prisoner,Criminal);

h  = new Human('Anne')                   // > Human {name: "Anne"}
c  = new Criminal('Jack','theft')        // > Criminal {name: "Jack", crime: "theft"}
p1 = new Prisoner('John','murder',21);   // > Prisoner successfully created!
p2 = new Prisoner('Peter','robbery',7);  // > Prisoner successfully created!
```